# C++ - Linux/shell script run child processes & get their return statuses

Tags: c++, linux, bash, process, execute

I'm looking for a solution to writing a piece of program in C++ on Linux that parses a file which contains programs with a set arguments, then runs those programs with their arguments arguments.

Each program (line) is executed one at a time and then the parent process waits for each child to exit and inspects it's exit status (i'm only interested if it is 0).

Example of text to be parsed:

prog1 -a arg1 -m arg2 -c arg3
prog2 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
....

I believe it is best to store everything in a vector of strings, eg:

```
vector <std::string> p_vector;
while (getline(file, line))
    p_vector.push_back(line);
```

then, for each element i from 0 to p_vector.size() I need to do something like the example I found on the net:

```
if(fork() = 0) //? shouldn't here be == ?
{
    execv(fullpath,argv);//does full path mean my p_vector[i]? or the child process and then argv is a list of space delimited arguments?
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    int *status;
    wait(status);
    if(*status == 0)
    printf("%s exited correctly", fullpath);//fullpath, right?
    else
    //other printf error
}
```

or, should I better use for this

```
string command = p_vector[i]; // eg: ls -l -a -l folder_one , put more arguments because I do not know the exact number of them for each parsed line

int exitCode = system(command.c_str());
```

If anyone has also an idea of how to do this using a script, that would be welcome too, although the scope of my question is C++!

I could have used Qt's QProcess as I know how to use that one but that might raise some legal issues of which I'm now aware right now (there's no problem with sharing the code however, the company I work for may not allow that)

Thanks and looking forward to getting some answers from you!

Comment: Where did you find this terrible, terrible example?

Comment: yes, there **should** be `==`

Comment: I found that example from http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=771930&page=17 . It looked suspicious but I have to do that by tommorrow morning and I don't have anything to test that on right now (Linux pc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Ignacio. But if you have to do it , then I would prefer you using System/popen command.

BUT MAKE SURE YOU ARE NOT RUNNING ANY COMMAND THAT WOULD LAND YOU TO TROUBLE.. like " rm -rf * ".

This is very likely to happen if you are going to read from a file which cannot be trusted with.

And no need to copy it to new string you can do "system(p_vector[i].c_str());"

Comment: No I won't do that. All programs are actually tests written by me which send some CAN messages and handle the responses in callback functions. I need to do something to automate the process and just be aware of those that fail. No environment needs to be set up.

Comment: Okies :) . Then go for it. Hope performance of this doesnt matter to you, because if there are lots of commands that needs to be executed, then for every command you are forking a new process [either manually or by using system/popen] which is a costly operation.

Comment: Well, performance may be important. I think I'll stick up with system. I still have to execute one process at a time, so I think I should use something like 
    while (exitCode != 0 || exitCode != -1) //my defaults for pass & fail
    sleep (variableDelay); // don't take up any more resources untill process is finished, right?

Comment: When you get the exitcode from the system command, that means the process has finished executing [how else would you get the exitcode :) ]. You dont have to sleep .

Comment: @Johnny: In that case, what's wrong with `make`? You are running a bunch of tests. `make` does that very nicely.

Comment: @ArunMu, you're right, my question regarding sleep was totally dumb, I was caught up with async stuff which is new to me that I was thinking of something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in bash:

```
echo file | while read command
do
   eval $command
done
```

where `file` is the file containing, for each line, a program with his arguments

Comment: That looks nice, how do I interpret the exit status? Should I use something 
    like if ($? == 0) echo "right" or...

Comment: yes "$?" will give you exit status of the last run command. "if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then echo "yes" ; fi"

Comment: the script given by Saphrosit would suffice your requirement unless you have very specific requirement for the code to be in c++

Comment: I believe both are nice & ok.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `exec` family you are going to have to parse your `p_vector[i]` into tokens. The zeroth token identifies the program to be executed; the remaining specify arguments to the program. `execvp` emulates what your shell does: It searches for the program in the search path. `execv` expects you to go one step further. You need to specify the path to the program, but not necessarily full path; relative paths work just fine. One other little gotcha with regard to `exec`: The zeroth argument is supposed to be a replica of the program name. That's a lot of work in this case.

Essentially, `system` does the following:

```
int pid, status, wait_pid;
char * shell;

shell = getenv ("SHELL");
if (shell == 0) {
   // Deal with missing SHELL environment variable problem
   return -1;
}

pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    return -1;
}

else if (pid == 0) {
   execl (shell, shell, string_to_execute);
   return -1;
}

waited_pid = waitpid (pid, &status, wait_options);
if (waited_pid != pid) {
   return -1;
}

return status;
```

In other words, pretty much what you want.

**Edit 1**
One gotcha with `system`: It insecure as all get out. ArunMu already mentioned `rm -rf /`. What if some line contains `do_something_benign; rm -rf /` If you can trust the content of the file, using `system` is fine. If not, it is much better to use something like perl or some other scripting language that can be made to run in a safe mode.

**Edit 2**
Given the commentary, what is the driving factor that led you to want to write this in C or C++? A scripting language, or even better, a `test` target in your makefile is a better fit to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! There's no issue with security. I can trust the content. programs that are to be executed are already in /usr/bin so there should be no path problem I believe. So the string_to_execute that you used is the full line from the vector, no splitting needed, right?

Comment: Well, the fact that I'm not sure which type (c or script) the client would prefer. Also, I may or may not be allowed to share the final code.